# How to slow down HTTP requests sent from Javascript

Tags: javascript

I clean up a bit but in my Postman collection I do a complex test that needs to retrieve data 100.000 times from an endpoint and then do some other tests. The API is hosted in the Cloud and replies SUPER fast but the issue is on Postman...

My code works fine if I do like 200 tests but with 100.000 the Postman crashes.
I am pretty sure the issue is because all the HTTP requests are being sent async and the application cannot handle to many.
So I tried to implement a delay in the requests sent using a `setTimeout` but it does not wait at all, it spams HTTP requests.

This is postman so I don't really think I can import other external libs...

```js
let counter = 0;
const counterCompleted = 100000;

// My loop for 100000 elements
pm.test(`my test should reply OK`, (done) => {
setTimeout(() => {
  const payload = {
    // data
  };
  pm.sendRequest({
      url: pm.request.url,
      method: 'POST',
      header: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: {
        mode: 'raw',
        raw: JSON.stringify(payload),
      },
    },
    (err, response) => {
      pm.expect(err).to.be.null;
      pm.expect(response).to.have.status(200);
      const data = response.json()[0];
      // storing my data
      counter++;
      if (counter === counterCompleted) {
        // When all requests are completed, do more tests
      }
      done();
    }
  );
});
}, 1000);
});
```

What can I do to slow down the requests?

Comment: just to explain why it's not working.. it seems to me you are only delaying the spam by 1 second.. they will all occur at once 1 second later than asked. Maybe you should instead create chunks.. delaying the execution of a whole group of tests

Comment: I tried 10 seconds. The settimeout does nothing in postman

Comment: You have to spread out the times. The first one can be 0 seconds in the future, the next one 1 second, the next 2, and so on.

Comment: Now, note that 100,000 requests a second apart will take 100,000 seconds, over 27 hours.

Comment: @asdasdf I don't know why you tried 10seconds and how it responded to the suggestion to make chunks. Anyway now beyond the scenario and postman itself.. the point is how many sendRequest you are invoking all at once. you can do also 10000s .. but you will have 100.000 routines running together after 10000s. It's pointless. You should focus on a chunk of those 100.000, run that chunk and wait until all are resolved.. then execute the next chunk